# one site or many?

Tags: asp.net, web, virtual-directory

I have about 10-12 websites (main site is classic ASP, others are ASP.NET 2). Each site has his own virtual directory. They are related to each other, mainly from main site other sites are calling to perform some service. Each site has from 2 to 5 pages. Does it make sense to unite them and create one bigger site with one virtual directory and one project in VS? Or leave them as they are separately? What are pro and contras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute first rule to follow here is:  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

If you really DO need to redo these sites, the only real concern to me is this: Do the sites share login or session data?  If so, they must be one site.  If not, it doesn't really matter.  The primary advantage to being separate sites (to me anyway) is that you can deploy them separately... you don't have to do everything at once, and you can easily test one at a time, and recycle its app pool as needed.

The advantage of making them one site...  Well.  Frankly, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Actually, yes, session can be shared (now it's not) and they use the same autentification mechanism (access to LDAP). I just wander if it will be easy to maintain and deploy.

Comment: Other thought, it's easy to support links between sites, because we have 3 environments: development, testing and production and for links I should use or Server Variables or keep server name in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Can't really answer the question without more info, but one code-base is easier to maintain than 10-12 in any language or framework.